# Confusion with Python for loop and range()

Tags: python

Here's my `for` loop that does stuff:

```
for x in range(0, 100):
    currentRate10 = srall10[x].current_rate
    startRate10 = srall10[x].start_rate
    lessons10 = srall10[x].sr_completed
    if currentRate10 is not None and startRate10 is not None:
        gain10 = currentRate10 - startRate10
    else:
        gain10 = 0
    rateavg = gain10 / lessons10
```

`rateavg` returns `1.42`. Seems accurate to me. However, when I put a variable in place of the `100` OR anything above `100`, I get `0` returned back. So if I change `100` to `101`, `rateavg` returns `0`. If I put in a variable that contains `143`, I still get `0`.

`srall10` contains a list

```
srall10 = DBSession.query(Summary).filter(Summary.sid == 6933).filter(
    Summary.sr_completed.between(1, 10)).all()
```

There are `143` entries, this was found by the exact same query except with `count()` at the end instead of `all()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not loop over `srall10` directly instead of using `range()` then? `for sr in srall:`. But it's your actual *values* that might cause the problem. Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Is it possible that current_rate or start_rate of srall10 is None?  If so, rateavg will equal 0.  
Also, unless there is more for your loop to do, this is only giving you the value for the very last position, so there is no need to loop here.

Comment: Can't. Get a `TypeError('list indices must be integers, not Summary',)` This is python 2

Comment: You want to calculate the average star rate of all records?

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate the average rate for all records.

Comment: From what I see you calculate the `rateavg` for each row, but in the end the `rateavg` value will be to the last calculated record

Comment: Try using 'rateavg += gain10 / lessons10' to sum them all up.  Do you want the rateavg for ALL records, or for EACH record?

Comment: If this is Python 2, take into account that if *both* operands to the `/` division operator are integers, then you get *floor division*. Use `float()` on one of the operands to force floating point (true) division instead or use `from __future__ import true_division` at the top of your module.

Comment: Already have `from __future__ import division` and get an `unresolved reference` error from Pycharm if I add `true_` to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `rateavg` as the result of the last item. and `range(0, 100)` will not iterate over all elements. Instead iterate directly over the list.

```
l = []
for s in srall10:
    if s.current_rate is not None and s.start_rate is not None:
        gain10 = s.current_rate - s.start_rate
    else:
        gain10 = 0
    l.append(gain10 / lessons10)  # average if each item

# total average
total_average = sum(l) / len(l)
```

Comment: Returning correctly. Going to check the math now to be sure that's correct. Why is `range()` not the way to go here?

Comment: Because you don't go over the whole list. And what if you have less items than 100? You will get `IndexError`.

Comment: Indeed, which was why I was originally using a variable, `range(0, srcount10)` which returned 1 through 143. I originally thought it was a variable issue so I tried hardcoding in the numbers, but noticed an issue whenever it was above 100, even though there were more than 100 to loop through

Comment: why use the range when you can iterate over the list? And if you did use the count, that was ok. Only that you were calculation individually the averages. The `count` implied another SQL to the database.

Comment: I didn't think I could lol, kept getting that `TypeError` mentioned in the third comment on my question. Was going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Python will always return an integer value for the division of two integers, so when a division operation in Python returns 0 and you were expecting a number, the first thing to check is whether both the dividend and the divisor are integers.  If so, and if the dividend is less than the divisor, then you'll get 0 instead of a float between 0 and 1.

You can avoid this with:

```
 rateavg = (gain10 * 1.0) / lessons10
```

I don't know if this is your problem since there's not enough information in the question to determine the type of the values in your lists, but it's often *my* problem when division unexpectedly returns 0.

Comment: Still getting 0. This was my thought previously so I changed `gain` to `gain = 1` in my `else`